# mouse collison not working with pygame sprite class

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am making a game using python and pygame. I have created a class called 'Pin_Sprite' with a parent of 'pygame.sprite.Sprite'. I want to print something when I mouseover 'Pin_sprite'. I've tried some code but nothing seems to work. My code is below:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
SCREEN_SIZE = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 832, 756))
icn = pygame.image.load("Imgs\phavicon-32x32.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("Canada Begins")
pygame.display.set_icon(icn)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE.size)
map1 = pygame.image.load("map1.png")
mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
prologue = False
class Pin_sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Pin_sprite, self).__init__()
        #adding all the images to sprite array
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_2.png.'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_5.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_6.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_7.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_8.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Frames\Pin\pin_frame_9.png'))


        #index value to get the image from the array
        #initially it is 0 
        self.index = 0

        #now the image that we will display will be the index from the image array 
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

        #creating a rect at position x,y (5,5) of size (150,198) which is the size of sprite 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 31, 32)

    def update(self):
        #when the update method is called, we will increment the index
        self.index += 1

        #if the index is larger than the total images
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            #we will make the index to 0 again
            self.index = 0

        #finally we will update the image that will be displayed
        screen.blit(self.images[self.index], (627, 311))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.images[self.index], (627, 311))


def map(x,y):
    screen.blit(map1, (x,y))


def LevelSelect():

    xx = 0 
    yy = 0
    mapx = 0
    mapy = 0

    mapbk = pygame.image.load("mapbk.png")

    pin = Pin_sprite()

    while True:
        screen.blit(mapbk, (0, 0))

        # x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # print(str(x) + ", " + str(y))

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        map(0, 0) 
        pin.update()

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(10)

LevelSelect()
```

I would really like some help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the location of the sprite in the `.rect` attribute. Use [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to get the a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the sprite and set the location by the keyword argument (`topleft = (627, 311)`):

```py
class Pin_sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (627, 311))

    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.images[self.index], self.rect)
```

Note, if you use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) then you don't need the `Pin_sprite.draw`method at all. You can use [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw), which use the `.image` and `.rect` attributes of the contained objects to draw the sprites.

---

Get the current mouse position by [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html) and use [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to evaluate if the mouse is on the sprite:

```py
def LevelSelect():
    # [...]

    pin = Pin_sprite()
    while True:
        screen.blit(mapbk, (0, 0))

        # [...]

        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pin.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            # draw text
            # [...]

        # [...]
```

Comment: How would i blit the pin obj to the screen, if this method is uesd??

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76 for helping me with this issue.

Comment: I tried putting the change it my code but nothing happened.

Comment: @Rabdid76 I am using python 3.7.2

Comment: @WatchWithVeer so you made a mistake. I ve tested my code, of course.